# Get old version of android opencv (2.4.7)

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I am searching for older versions of opencv for android, googling "android opencv 2.4.7 download" brings to me to following sites:

1) http://opencv.org/downloads.html but there are not listed every version

2) https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/releases here are no android versions

I have to build an older app and need therefore exactly that aversion.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find a builded package on the opencv official site for version 2.4.7 for android, that's  sure.

One what you can do is to download 2.4.7 tag source from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/releases/tag/2.4.7) and build it using [this](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk) tutorial to build the suitable executable for you.

Comment: but those versions have been around once, why are they gone?

Comment: Simply they cannot hold all builded binaries for all versions and for all targets. Opencv 3.0 is on the way now so they removed "old" builds with reasoning one can build from the sources.